# ubuntu server/samba file sharing disconnection during use

Tags: networking, server, samba

I apologise in advance if i include needless information;

Firstly my network is setup with ubuntu server 12.04 LTS -> netgear modem router -> ethernet cable -> belkin router as wireless access point -> main computer(win7) and laptop(win8) connected here.

So I installed and setup webmin and samba, and had to mount my 4 existing NTFS hard drives (full of content). I then used webmins samba windows file shares to share the mounted hard drives. When I go to my windows computers I am able to see the fileserver, and see all the mounted shares; as well as access webmin.

However, as an example, when I start playing a video off the server on the windows computers after a time ranging from 1 to 10 minutes, the server disconnects. And then I can no longer log into webmin through browser either. However if at the same time one of the computers stops working, I can go to the other computer and still log into webmin.
I am often trying to play a video on the main computer before I lose complete access to the fileserver, but then I can log into webmin on the other computer?

I have absolutely no idea what might be causing this issue so any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the explanation of your network config correct? i.e. is the server upstream of the Netgear router, connected to the router WAN port?